# Facebook event creation through iPhone app and Facebook Connect

Tags: iphone, facebook

How is this done? Is it even possible?

All the function calls seem correct, but the result is always false:

```
NSString *event = @"{\"name\":\"A party\",\"start_time\":\"1215929160\",\"end_time\":\"1215929160\",\"location\":\"Somewhere\"}";
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:event forKey:@"event_info"];
[[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.events.create" params:params];
```

Comment: Please provide more information about what you are doing and include code samples.  Then, please ask a specific question so that we can help you.  From what you have provided so far the answer is yes, it is possible, but without more info from you I don't know what else to say to help you figure out what is wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to ask about permissions:

```
  FBPermissionDialog* dialog = [[[FBPermissionDialog alloc] init] autorelease];
  dialog.delegate = self;
  dialog.permission = @"create_event";
  [dialog show];
```